# How to make rock, paper, scissor game repeat?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently working on a class assignment, have my html and js files written.  My main issue is that I am unable to have the computer grab a new random number thus it will only keep one pick (rock, paper, or scissor).  I also tried to make sure the game doesn't last longer than 5 games but am having issues even attempting it.

My HTML: (including whats necessary only, still an ongoing project for class)

> 4 buttons, one for each pick, and one to compare the answer

```
<button onClick='choose("rock")'>
    Rock
    <img src="images/rock.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="rock">
</button>
<button onClick='choose("paper")'>
    Paper
    <img src="images/paper.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="paper">
</button>
<button onClick='choose("scissors")'>
    Scissors
    <img src="images/scissors.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="scissprs">
</button>
<button onClick='compare(user, computerChoice)'>
    Go!
</button>

<p id="result">Winner: </p>
<p id="playerscore">Player Score:</p>
<p id="computerscore">Computer Score: </p>
```

My JS: (intentionally left out conditions for all except one and some replaced with "...")

```
    var user;
var choose = function(choice) {
    user = choice;
}
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if(computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} 
else if(computerChoice < 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} 
else{
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}


var playerscore = 0;
var computerscore = 0;
var game = 0;
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {


else if(choice1 == "paper") {
    if(choice2 == "rock") {
        ...
        playerscore++;
        game++;
        document.getElementById("playerscore").innerHTML = playerscore;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Computer Wins on Scissors";
        computerscore++;
        game++;
        document.getElementById("computerscore").innerHTML = computerscore;
    }
}

}
};
```

So from here what can I do to make my webpage repeat this script until five games have been played?  I tried using a do-while loop but kept coming up with a: compare not declared issue, and user not declared when I tried to put it all in one function called rockpaperscissors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your game (Completely working)

```js
var playerscore = 0;
var computerscore = 0;
var userChoice;
var computerChoice;

function choose(choice) {
  userChoice = choice;
}

function compMakeAchoice() {
  computerChoice = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
  alert(computerChoice);
  if (computerChoice == 1) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
  } else if (computerChoice == 2) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
  } else if (computerChoice == 3) {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
  }
}

function compare() {
  compMakeAchoice();
  if ((computerChoice == "rock" && userChoice == "rock") || (computerChoice == "paper" && userChoice == "paper") || (computerChoice == "scissors" && userChoice == "scissors")) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Winner: " + "No one won. Both chose " + userChoice;
  } else if ((computerChoice == "rock" && userChoice == "paper") || (computerChoice == "paper" && userChoice == "scissors") || (computerChoice == "scissors" && userChoice == "rock")) {
    playerscore++;
    document.getElementById("playerscore").innerHTML = "Player Score: " + playerscore;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Winner: " + "You won (Your Choice:" + userChoice + " and Computer's choice:" + computerChoice + ")";
  } else {
    computerscore++;
    document.getElementById("computerscore").innerHTML = "Computer Score: " + computerscore;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Winner: " + "Computer won (Your Choice:" + userChoice + " and Computer's choice:" + computerChoice + ")";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onClick='choose("rock")'>Rock</button>
<button onClick='choose("paper")'>Paper</button>
<button onClick='choose("scissors")'>Scissors</button>
<button onClick='compare()'>Go!</button>

<p id="result">Winner:</p>
<p id="playerscore">Player Score:</p>
<p id="computerscore">Computer Score:</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a hidden div / input where you set set your value of variable "game". That way you are able to proof the Number of Game after a Game is done. if The Number is 5 you change your html from 4 buttons to "congratz" or whatever.